# Listing shared calendars using EWS-Java-API

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am using [EWS-Java-API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) for exchange server and java communication. I need way to access a shared calendar.

E.g. user1@xyz.com is one user who is creating a calender and shared to user2@xyz.com. Now I want to retrieve list of shared calendar using user2@xyz.com's credential which is shared with him. Can any one help me how we can do it?

Comment: I have found way to get folder using below code  `CalendarFolder cf = CalendarFolder.bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(email)));`